# Capture Multiple images using CameraApi2 android

Tags: android, camera

i'm developing android app using the new camera api i'm trying to capture multiple images in sequence what i'm trying to do is capture multiple images in one second but it only output two images and stop
 here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "CameraStress";
    private android.util.Size mPreviewSize;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;

    private Button ButtonCap;
    Timer mTimer = null;
    // Handler handler;
    static int count = 0;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    /**
     * Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation.
     */
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic);

        Log.e(TAG, "In OnCreate");

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);

        ButtonCap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        ButtonCap.setOnClickListener(onClickPicture); {

                Log.e(TAG, "Button Clicked");
                takePicture();
            }
       }

    protected void takePicture() {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG, "takePicture");
            }
        });
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mCameraDevice is null, return");
            return;
        }

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces;
        outputSurfaces = null;
        try {
            String CameraID = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraID);

            StreamConfigurationMap configs = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            android.util.Size[] sizes;

            // JPEG format support
            sizes = configs.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            int picWidth = 2592;
            int picHeight = 1944;


            // We use an ImageReader to get a JPEG from CameraDevice.
            // Here, we create a new ImageReader and prepare its Surface as an output from camera.

            ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(picWidth, picHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);

            outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(imageReader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            Handler backgroundHandler = null;
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = null;
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroundHandler);

            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture,CreateCapture request.

            final CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

//  mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);

            builder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));



            readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }

                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                     Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);

                     final File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "count"+n+".jpg");
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "10");
                        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, "10");
                        exif.saveAttributes();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            };


            // We create a Handler since we want to handle the result JPEG in a background thread

            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Camera Picture");
            thread.start();
            backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, backgroundHandler);


            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "JPEG Saved");
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Image Captured Successfully");
                    // We restart the preview when the capture is completed
                    startPreview();
                }
            };

            //mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            //mCaptureSession.capture();


            final Handler finalBackgroundHandler = backgroundHandler;
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    try {
                  //      session.capture(builder.build(), CaptureCallback, finalBackgroundHandler);
                        // This is for capturing an image
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(),CaptureCallback,finalBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                }
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    }


    private void openCamera() {

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera E");
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {


        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable, width=" + width + ",height=" + height);
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface,
                                                int width, int height) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
        }

    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onDisconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onError");
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }


    protected void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

        if (texture == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "texture is null");
            return;
        }

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        Log.e(TAG, "In Start Preview");
        try {

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.

        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "onConfigureFailed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updatePreview() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "In Update Preview");
        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Camera Preview");
        thread.start();
        Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

        // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
        // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.

        try {
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onClickPicture = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.v(TAG,"In ON click");
            takePicture();
          mTimer = new Timer();


            mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            Looper.loop();
                            takePicture();
                        }
                    };

                    thread.start();

                }
            },5,2000);


        }
    };
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?